# Reusing Base Linq Query from one method to another

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to remove duplicate code throughout my project and I am at a standstill trying to figure this out. What I am trying to do is create a base linq query that will be reused to add things like Where, Take...etc in multiple different methods.

```
public IQueryable<Object> FooLinq(int id)
{
    using (var ctx = new dbEntities())
    {
        var results =
            (from account in ctx.account
                join memberProducts in ctx.tblMemberProducts on account.Id equals memberProducts.AccountId                 
                orderby account.date descending
                select new{account,memberProducts}).ToList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

So that would be by base query above and I would have a seperate method that would reuse VioLinq but this time would use a where clause in it.

```
public List<IncomingViolations> Foo1(int id)
{
    //Linq query FooLinq() where Name == "Bob"
}
```

Comment: Why are you specifically materializing a query into its result set when you actually want a query instead of the materialized results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do two things:

1. Return the query prior to materializing it.
2. Make sure the context is still in scope when the final query is materialized.

These two requirements will play off each other somewhat, and there are a number of approaches you can take to meet them.

For example, you could make your method take the context as a parameter, forcing the caller to provide it and manage its lifecycle.

```
public IQueryable<AccountInfo> FooLinq(DbEntities ctx, int id)
{
        return
                from account in ctx.account                        
                orderby account.date descending
                select new AccountInfo()
                {
                    Name = account.Name,
                    Mid = account.MemberID,
                    Date = account.Date,
                    Address = account.Address,

                };
}

public List<IncomingViolations> Foo1(int id)
{
    using(var ctx = new dbEntities())
    {
        //Linq query FooLinq() where Name == "Bob"
        return FooLinq(ctx).Where(v => v.Name == "Bob").ToList();
    }
}
```

You could alternatively inject the context as a constructor-injected dependency, and use a DI framework to manage the context's lifecycle.

Comment: Ok, that worked great. But I guess I made a mistake. I have changed the select in FooLinq, Please see above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as Queryable then add conditions to it.
For example:

```
public List<account> GetAccountsByName(string name, bool usePaging, int offset = 0, int take = 0) {
   var query = GetMyQuery();
   query = query.Where(x => x.Name == name);
   query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
   if(usePaging) {
      query = query.Take(take).Skip(offset);
   }
   query = PrepareSelectForAccount(query);
   return query.ToList();    .
}

public IQueryable<account> GetMyQuery(){
 return ctx.account.AsQueryable();
}
public IQueryable<account> PrepareSelectForAccount(IQueryAble<account> query){
     return query.Select(select new AccountInfo()
                {
                    Name = account.Name,
                    Mid = account.MemberID,
                    Date = account.Date,
                    Address = account.Address,

                }
      );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, but don't call `.ToList()`, and return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. LINQ is based on the concept of [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) which means the query is not actually *performed* until the enumerable is iterated over. Until then, all you have done is built an object which knows *how* to do the query when the time comes.

By returning an `IQueryable<T>` from a function that sets up the "basic query," you are then free to tack on additional LINQ methods (such as `.Where()` or `.Take()`) to produce a modified query. At this point you are still simply setting up the query; it is actually performed only when you iterate over the enumerable, or call something like `.ToList()` which does that for you.

Comment: Returning an `IEnumerable<T>` is going to result in any operations added to the query by the caller will only ever be done in memory, and not through the underlying query provider.  The query provider is going to do a much better job of it, most likely, and if not, the caller can choose to convert it to an `IEnumerable<T>` themselves.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I've updated the answer to suggest `IQueryable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` to take advantage of the query provider's implementation.

Comment: Your edit (using `IQueryable<>`) is better, but still not complete. Discuss options for ensuring the context is within scope at the point where the final query gets materialized.